# How to find an item with a specific start string in a set

Tags: python, regex, set, startswith

I have a set of ~10 million items which look something like this:

```
1234word:something
4321soup:ohnoes
9cake123:itsokay
[...]
```

Now I'd need to quickly check if an item witha specific start is in the set.
For example

```
x = "4321soup"
is x+* in a_set:
     print ("somthing that looks like " +x +"* is in the set!")
```

How do I accomplish this? I've considered using a regex, but I have no clue whether it is even possible in this scenario.

Comment: did you want to print the lines which starts with `4321soup` ?

Comment: Head's up: if you truly have something like 10M entries in your set, you might be better off with a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: I agree with @inspectorG4dget, python set is not a good structure for such a task. Better use tree, or sorted sequence to get result in  `O(log(n))` instead of O(n) time

Comment: I want check if an entry, starting with `4321soup` is in the set or not. 
I haven't decided yet if I really want to use a set for the project, I will definitely look into the trie as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
^4321soup.*$
```

Yes it is possible.Try match.If result is positive you have it.If it is `None` you dont have it.

Do not forget to set `m` and `g` flags.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/28

Answer (score 0):

use [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) instead of using regex, if you want to match only with the start of the string, also considering the number of lines you are having ~10 million items

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str = "1234word:something";
print str.startswith( '1234' );
```

python, considering your contents are inside a file named "mycontentfile"

```
>>> with open("mycontentfile","r") as  myfile:
...     data=myfile.read()
... 
>>> for item in data.split("\n"):
...     if item.startswith("4321soup"):
...             print item.strip()
... 
4321soup:ohnoes
```

Comment: why do you suggest to use `.startswith()` instad of regex? just because its less complex or is it also faster? Also, how do I use the `.startswith()` in the `is x in set:`?

Comment: sir this is less complex and faster than doing with regex. I myself am a big fan of using regex but lets just not use in this condition. we will have to loop and check for each line whether the startswith succeeds. I ll get back with the code if you need.

Comment: I think a loop trough ~10 million entries would be somewhat too slow for my project, as suggested above I'll try to use a tree or sorted sequence

Comment: you cant avoid looping whether you do it via regex or startswith

Comment: Don't use the name `str`, it shadows the built-in. Also, please see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @jonrsharpe that was just an example sir, I have provided the code for the op below it.

Comment: @DaedalusMythos consodering your input is in a file. I have written the code to retrieve the elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hash-set's are very good for checking existance of some element, completely. In your task you need check existence of starting part, not complete element. That's why better use tree or sorted sequence instead of hash mechanism (internal implementation of python set).

However, according to your examples, it looks like you want to check whole part before ':'. For that purpose you can buildup set with these first parts, and then it will be good for checking existence with sets:

```
items = set(x.split(':')[0] for x in a_set) # a_set can be any iterable

def is_in_the_set(x):
    return x in items

is_in_the_set("4321soup")  # True
```

Comment: this looks quite good but in this case - if I understood correctly - I'd have to save the complete set twice (once with both values `x:y` = a_set and once with `x` = items only) which would grow too big for the amount of entries I have. 
I'm currently thinking that the most reasonable solution would be something like a sorted tree of dicts (key = x and value = y) and the tree is sorted by the dicts keys. - no clue how to do that though

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the importance is how to iterate set in the optimistic way.
Since you should check every result until you find the matching result, the best way is create a generator (list expression form) and execute it until you find a result.
To accomplish this, I should use [next](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/functions.html?highlight=next#next) approach.

```
a_set = set(['1234word:something','4321soup:ohnoes','9cake123:itsokay',]) #a huge set
prefix = '4321soup' #prefix you want to search
next(x for x in a_set if x.startswith(prefix), False) #pass a generator with the desired match condition, and invoke it until it exhaust (will return False) or until it find something
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently thinking that the most reasonable solution would be
>   something like a sorted tree of dicts (key = x and value = y) and the
>   tree is sorted by the dicts keys. - no clue how to do that though – 
>   Daedalus Mythos

No need for a *tree of dicts* ... just a single dictionary would do. If you have the key:value pairs stored in a dictionary, let's say `itemdict`, you can write

```
x = "4321soup"
if x in itemdict:
    print ("something that looks like "+x+"* is in the set!")
```